# Identical aggregate-function for different WHERE's

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Im stuck atm. Trying to figure out how to use an aggregate function like SUM(column1*column2) for making results in multiple columns. I want to print ex. SUM(qty*unitprice) where orderdate between "blabla" and "blabla",

and then i want another column which uses the same function(sum(qty*unitprice)
but with additional expressions in the where clause. this is my code example, it doesnt show anything:

```
select Orderdates, Sales, SalesDisc
FROM (  select month(OH.OrderDate) as Orderdates, sum(OD.OrderQty*OD.UnitPrice) as Sales
        from sales.SalesOrderDetail OD
        inner join sales.salesorderheader OH on
        OD.SalesOrderID = OH.SalesOrderID
        where OrderDate >= ('2014-01-01') and OrderDate < ('2015-01-01')
        group by month(OH.orderdate)    
     ) A 

     Join
        (select month(OH.OrderDate) as orderdatez, sum(OD.OrderQty*OD.UnitPrice) as SalesDisc
        from sales.SalesOrderDetail OD
        inner join sales.SalesOrderHeader OH on 
        OD.SalesOrderID = OH.SalesOrderID
        where OrderDate >= ('2014-01-01') and OrderDate < ('2015-01-01')
        and OD.SpecialOfferID between 2 and 16
        Group by Month(OH.orderdate)
        ) B
        on A.Orderdates = B.orderdatez and A.Sales = B.SalesDisc
```

Comment: Are you sure that the last join should include `and A.Sales = B.SalesDisc` ? It looks a bit odd to join on an aggregate; try removing that part. Also, unless you have data for all months present in both queries, maybe the join should be a `left join`

Comment: Goodness gracious! ur right... TY!

Comment: Check out @NoDisplayName answer it is better way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If am not wrong this is what you need

```
SELECT Month(OH.OrderDate)             AS Orderdates,
       Sum(OD.OrderQty * OD.UnitPrice) AS Sales,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN OD.SpecialOfferID BETWEEN 2 AND 16 THEN ( OD.OrderQty * OD.UnitPrice )
             ELSE 0
           END)                        AS SalesDisc
FROM   sales.SalesOrderDetail OD
       INNER JOIN sales.salesorderheader OH
               ON OD.SalesOrderID = OH.SalesOrderID
WHERE  OrderDate >= ( '2014-01-01' )
       AND OrderDate < ( '2015-01-01' )
GROUP  BY Month(OH.orderdate)
```

**Note :** It will be more meaningful if you add `year(OH.orderdate)` in `group by`

Comment: Ty! It looks more optimized. I need month cuz im doing charts in ssrs, need date to be int for naming months to Jan,Feb etc. Cheers

Comment: @Blixter - if the orderdate range is between more than one year than you need to add year in `group by.`